# Shell script read user input

Tags: bash, shell, input

I got stuck on this shell script code where it requires user to enter the group number and find the largest and the average out of that group number.
My code ATM only works with passing the group number as a command-line argument. How to prompt for the group number as user input?

```
read n

    if [ $n -ge 1 ]; then

    sum=0

     count=$n

     max=-1000
    if [ $max -lt $1 ]; then

    max=$1

    fi

    while [ $n -ge 1 ]; do

            case $1 in
            [0-9] | [1-9][0-9])
            sum=`expr $sum +$1`;;
            -[1-9] | -[1-9][0-9])
            sum=`expr $sum + $1`;;


    done

    if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then

    avg=`expr $sum / $count`

    echo The largest number is $max

    echo The average number is $avg
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? You already know that you can use `read`, show how you tried to use it so we can help you fix it. Please only post the necessary code - two or three lines around how you're attempting to do it should be enough. Please [edit] your question to show that.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment.. and I'm really sorry coz I'm still new to this.. i had edited my code .. bt still not sure ..how the read command really work..thanks

Answer (score 2):

From your comments it seems you would like to read values from `stdin` rather than from the command line. To do that in Bash you use the `read` builtin:

```
read -ep "Enter group number: " group
printf "Entered %d\n" $group
```

For interactive prompting it is usually put in the test part of a `while` loop where you can break if the input is invalid:

```
shopt -s extglob
while read -ep "Enter group number: " group; do
    case $group in 
        ?(-)+([0-9]))    # valid input
            # compute average here
        *) break ;;      # not valid input
    esac
done
```

See `help read` for more information.

Comment: @user3079769 Good. Now, you may want to upvote - or even accept - an answer that you think is helpful or that solves your problem. That's how it works on stackexchange sites. If you still have problems, you should edit your original question with new info.

Answer (score 0):

You're working way too hard, and your script is way too verbose.  Try:

```
#!/bin/sh

test $# -gt 0 || { echo Please enter at least one argument >&2; exit 1; }
max=0
for x; do
  test "$max" -lt $x && max=$x
  test $? -gt 1 && exit 1
  : $(( count += 1 ))
  : $(( sum +=  x ))
done

echo max = $max
printf "avg = "
expr $sum / $count
```

Since you used `expr` in your script, I'm doing the same, but be aware that all of the arithmetic will be done in the integers (so the reported average will be the greatest integer less than the actual average, and non-integer input will be considered an error).   This solution relies on `test` returning a value greater than 1 when it encounters an error (eg, non integer input), which is the behavior specified by  [the open group.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128)

Also note that this puts the error message on `stderr` (where error messages belong) and returns a non-zero value to indicate that the script failed.